# i'm making telegram bot with aiogram

Tags: python, error-handling, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(commands=['reply'])
async def reply(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
    markup.add(types.KeyboardButton('Site'))
    markup.add(types.KeyboardButton('Website'))
    await message.answer('Hello', reply_markup=markup)
```

error code:

```
 File "C:\BotChatGPT\main.py", line 24, in <module>
    @dp.callback_query_handler(commands=['reply'])
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

i didn't to do anything, i don't have enough experience

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a handler that receives a message, and you register it as a callback_query.Which is not correct.Try this:

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands=['reply'])
```